Unable to run React Native project
I'm trying scine long time to run React Native project on Android in Windows. But still unable to run. Every I try I get this error
BUILD FAILED in 9m 6s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Settings file 'D:\Projects\LearnApp\android\settings.gradle' line: 2 * What went wrong: Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] > java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (D:\Projects\LearnApp\android\.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10-53e7ebf8-a832-4e54-a04e-14148b365b22) to immutable location (D:\Projects\LearnApp\android\.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10) * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 9m 6s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I've tried much but still no solution worked yet.
Please help, I've tried with different node js & Jave versions but no luck
Thanks

Possibly related GitHub discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/46210 - it seems like it might be related to (windows user) permissions / the Gradle version.
